# How to get Ajax response within a Module?

Tags: joomla-3.x, ajax

I am coding my first experimental administrator/module so that I can understand how Joomla performs ajax calls.  I only need to refresh the content of my module with some server info and a couple of Google Charts calls. I want to use Joomla techniques so that I can confidently build more modules in the future using best practices.

I have cut out 90% of the functionality from my project to isolate where I am stuck.

**mod_filefinder.php**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';
if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$filefinder = new FileFinder(JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getString('path'));
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_filefinder');
```

**helper.php**

```
class FileFinder
{
    public $currentdirectory = "";
    public $subdirectories = array();
    public $js = "";
    public $html = "";
    function __construct($path = null)
    {
        if (!$path) {
            chdir('../');
            $this->currentdirectory = basename(JPATH_BASE);
            $this->subdirectories = glob($this->currentdirectory.DS."*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            $this->html = "container";
            $this->js = "
                    jQuery(function($) {
                        $('#path').on('change', function() {
                        var path = $(this).val();
                        console.log({path: path});
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'index.php?option=com_ajax&module=filefinder&method=FileFinder&format=raw',  // &ignoreMessages 
                            type: 'POST',
                            async: true,
                            cache: false,
                            data: {path: path},
                            success: function(response){
                                console.log(response); 
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    $('#path').trigger('change');
                });
             ";
        } else {
            $this->currentdirectory = $path;
            $this->subdirectories = glob($this->currentdirectory.DS."*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        }
    }

    public function FileFinderAjax() {
        ?><script>console.log('hello');</script><?php
        echo "hello";  // how do I get Ajax to get in here?!?
    }
}
```

**default.php**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if ($filefinder->html == "container") { // provide container with default contents
    echo "<div id=\"filefinder_container\">";
        echo "<span>", JTEXT::_("Current Directory"), " ", $filefinder->currentdirectory, "</span>";
        echo "<select id=\"path\"><option value=\"\">Select a Subdirectory</option>";
        foreach ($filefinder->subdirectories as $subdirectory) {
            echo "<option>$subdirectory</option>";  //  value=\"$filefinder->currentdirectory".DS."$subdirectory\"
        }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</div>";
} else {  // return only the new contents to be inserted into old container
    echo "<span>", JTEXT::_("Current Directory"), " ", $filefinder->currentdirectory, "</span>";
    echo "<select id=\"path\"><option value=\"\">Select a Subdirectory</option>";
    foreach ($filefinder->subdirectories as $subdirectory) {
        echo "<option>$subdirectory</option>";  //  value=\"$filefinder->currentdirectory".DS."$subdirectory\"
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
if ($filefinder->js) {
    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScriptDeclaration($filefinder->js);
}
```

I do have the `index.html` and `mod_filefinder.xml` files in place, I am just not adding them to my post because it is unnecessary bloat.

Right now, my console.log is displaying these things after I select a new directory:

> ```
> {path: "administrator\cache"}
> POST http://localhost/jdem01/administrator/index.php?option=com_ajax&module=filefinder&method=FileFinder&format=raw 404 (Not Found)
> ```

I have also tried:

- making `FileFinderAjax()` a `static` public function
- and approximately 50 hailmary code adjustments that I cannot recall and don't care to post.

I have fruitlessly read:

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/search-ajax/
https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module
[Sending POST data within module - AJAX](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/sending-post-data-within-module-ajax)
[Using AJAX in a custom module - how to do it?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20554/using-ajax-in-a-custom-module-how-to-do-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)
(... and countless other docs/forums/stackoverflow/stackexchange resources)
(... and all of the "Similar Questions" recommended in the yellow box to the right of my question textarea)

I am using Joomla 3.8.6

---

Update after preliminary support from @jamesgarrett and @Lodder...

I am just not getting the desired response string.

Here are my files (stripped down even farther):

**administrator/modules/mod_filefinder/mod_filefinder.php**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';    
$filefinder = new modFileFinderHelper();
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_filefinder');
```

**administrator/modules/mod_filefinder/helper.php**

```
class modFileFinderHelper
{
    function __construct() {
        $this->currentdirectory = basename(JPATH_BASE);
    }

    public function FileFinderAjax() {
        $data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getArray([]);
        $path = $data['data']['path'];
        ?><script>console.log('<?=$path?>');</script><?php
        echo "hello $path";
        JExit;
    }
}
```

**administrator/modules/mod_filefinder/tmpl/default.php**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('script', 'administrator/modules/mod_filefinder/ajax.js');

echo "<div id=\"filefinder_container\">{$filefinder->currentdirectory}</div>";
```

**administrator/modules/mod_filefinder/ajax.js**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function loadContent(path) {
        console.log({path: path});
        var request = {
            option       : 'com_ajax',
            module       : 'filefinder',  // to target: mod_filefinder
            method       : 'FileFinder',  // to target: function FileFinderAjax in class modFileFinderHelper
            format       : 'raw',
            data         : {path: path}
        };
        console.log(request);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: request
        })
        .success(function(response){
            console.log('response: '+response);
        });
    }
    console.log('onload, calling ajax with default path value: '+$('#filefinder_container').html());
    loadContent($('#filefinder_container').html());

    $('#path').on('change', function() {
        console.log('change event triggered, calling ajax with path value: '+$(this).val());
        loadContent($(this).val());
    });
});
```

This is my console.log data:

[image]

So let me try to ask this differently.

What is the simplest file structure that will allow me to:

1. Load an empty html structure.
2. Send an AJAX call to a single-purpose (build a json string) php file
3. Receive the json response and distribute the json data into the html structure

Simple right?  Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the ajax request to map to your module's helper the class must be named "modFilefinderHelper"

From the documentation:

> Module requests must include the module variable in the URL, paired
>   with the name of the module (i.e. module=session for mod_session).
>
> This value is also used for:
>
> The name of the directory to check for the helper file, e.g.
>   /modules/mod_session/helper.php The class name to call, e.g.
>   modSessionHelper

[relevant doc](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface)

---

Edit after question update

I've updated and commented two of the files where you're having problems

```
<?php
class modFileFinderHelper
{
    function __construct() {
        $this->currentdirectory = basename(JPATH_BASE);
    }

    // static methods only (the constructor above wont run for your ajax request)
    public static function FileFinderAjax() {
        // Here we get the data passed via ajax - note the values themselves have not been filtered!
        $data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('data',[],'array');

        // Presumably you would here do something worthwhile
        $response = [
            'something' => 12345,
            'your_path' => $data['path'],
        ];
        // Usually you can dump json and die, but there's a inbuild responder that'll encode things and die on your behalf
        // you'll see client side it also adds a few generic values like "success"
        echo new JResponseJson($response);
    }
}


jQuery(function($) {

    // grab a dom selector so we don't have to grab it each time we update
    var filefinder_container = $('#filefinder_container');

    function loadContent(path) {
        console.log({path: path});
        var request = {
            option       : 'com_ajax',
            module       : 'filefinder',  // to target: mod_filefinder
            method       : 'FileFinder',  // to target: function FileFinderAjax in class modFileFinderHelper
            format       : 'raw',
            data         : {path: path}
        };
        console.log(request);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: request
        })
        .success(function(response){
            console.log('response: '+response);
            // we've got json but we need an object so let's parse it!
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            // and now we can use it like this.
            filefinder_container.text(response.data.something + " and " + response.data.your_path);
        });
    }
    console.log('onload, calling ajax with default path value: '+$('#filefinder_container').html());
    loadContent($('#filefinder_container').html());

    $('#path').on('change', function() {
        console.log('change event triggered, calling ajax with path value: '+$(this).val());
        loadContent($(this).val());
    });
});
```

---

Also, it's not an issue with jQuery, but with some other FE frameworks like angularjs or vuejs you may/will run into an issue of Joomla been not aware of your input because it fed as real JSON, not a form. To get over it you'd like to add something like

```
$input = Factory::getApplication()->input;
$jsonInput = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if($jsonInput){
    foreach ($jsonInput as $k => $v){
        $input->def($k,$v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Those latest adjustments were just what  I needed.  Specifically, the static Ajax function and that magical `new JResponseJson()` call (which is nice because now I don't think I need to write a separate php file just to generate the response data).  Brilliant support, thanks.

Comment: glad you're on your way.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added a few additional lines, in the end, you'll see those after moderation goes through. Overall this would work as it is with jQuery, with something more advanced - you'll need those lines in PHP.

Comment: @jamesgarrett A quick question about `$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('data',[],'array');`  I am passing a data object from js like this: {"path":"something","exts":[]}, but JFactory is telling me that `isset($data['exts'])` is `false`.  Is there something magical in the filter parameter happening?

Comment: You can always dump the $_POST to the screen and die and read the response in dev tools. That’ll allow you to see the structure of the unfiltered data.

Answer (score 3):

Ok first thing is first, get your Javascript out of the PHP file and into a separate  `.js` file.

The file should be placed in the media directory, but just for temporary measure, just place it in the root of the module directory.

Here is the code with a couple of changes, such as passing the URL parameters through as a rwquest object, as opposed to a direct URL. This will help when working with multilingual websites and SEF URL's

**ajax.js:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var path = $('#path');

    path.on('change', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var request = {
            option       : 'com_ajax',
            module       : 'filefinder',
            method       : 'FileFinder',
            format       : 'raw',
            'data[path]' : value,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: request,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response); 
            }
        });

    });

    path.trigger('change');
});
```

---

The the revised code for the Helper with some additional code tweaks for you to get the Ajax data.

**helper.php:**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class ModfileFinderHelper
{
    public $currentdirectory = '';
    public $subdirectories = array();
    public $container = false;

    public function __construct($path = null)
    {
        if (!$path)
        {
            chdir('../');
            $this->currentdirectory = basename(JPATH_BASE);
            $this->subdirectories = glob($this->currentdirectory . DS . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            $this->container = true;

        }
        else
        {
            $this->currentdirectory = $path;
            $this->subdirectories = glob($this->currentdirectory . DS . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        }
    }

    public function FileFinderAjax()
    {
        $data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getArray([]);
        $path = $data['data']['server'];

        var_dump($path);
        exit;

        // Check the browser console (Network tab) and the path should be displayed under the "response"
    }
}
```

---

And finally the **default.php:**

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('script', 'modules/mod_filefinder/ajax.js');

?>

<?php if ($filefinder->container) : ?>
    <div id="filefinder_container">
<?php endif; ?>

    <span><?php echo JText::_('Current Directory') . ' ' . $filefinder->currentdirectory; ?></span>
    <select id="path">
        <option value="">Select a Subdirectory</option>
        <?php foreach ($filefinder->subdirectories as $subdirectory) : ?>
            <option><?php echo $subdirectory; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

<?php if ($filefinder->container) : ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

**mod_filefinder.php:**

Due to the class name change, update the following line in this file from:

```
$filefinder = new FileFinder(JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getString('path'));
```

to:

```
$path = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getString('path');
$filefinder = new ModfileFinderHelper($path);
```

Overall, just some code simplification and improvements here and there.

Hope this helps

---

**Security**

It's recommended to implement a token check for Ajax calls:

[How to add CSRF anti-spoofing to forms](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms)

Comment: I have made some more updates to the answer and also upvoted @mickmackusa's answer as he made a good point which I forgot about.

Comment: Hey @Lodder you've put your path.trigger('change'); inside the on change function instead of after it. Nom nom nom... recursion...

Comment: @jamesgarrett - Good spot. Not finished coffee yet

Comment: Lol. In Melbourne and am 3 wines in.

Comment: @mickmackusa - It's always better to use a separate `.js` file. This means you're CSP compliant and users can easily override the file is need be. You need to move the file to the `root/media/mod_filefinder` directory after though else users wont be able to override it.

Comment: @mickmackusa The console error provides an error about calling something statically. So it must be coming from some code that you've not shared.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Would you mind zipping up the module and sharing a link for me to download, so I can test on my localhost?